# Ungrammatical validation message for firefox

Tags: html

Firefox default messaging/validation message is grammatically incorrect.

Using the minlength html5 attribute Firefox is displaying the following words.

"Please use at least 3 characters (you are currently using 1 characters)."

Should say "1 character" is there a fix for this?

Html Below

```
<input type="text" minlength="3" />
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity

Comment: Thank you, I'll fix in the question

Comment: Getting singular/plural right is very complicated compared to self-driving cars or artificial intelligence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a bug in Firefox's implementation. There's no extremely simple way to correct this that I'm aware of.

You can use setCustomValidity to call a function that will check the length of the field and return an appropriate validation error, using correct grammar.